# SocialAuth verison 4.8, Facebook graph API V2.2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, facebook-graph-api, socialauth

I have upgraded SocialAuth verison 4.8, which includes Facebook graph API V2.2, but how will I ensure that for social login it is using facebook verison v2.2.

Thanks